# Shell to do action, when someone visited my webpage

Tags: shell-script, logs, php, webserver

Can someone make a script that beeps or does some action when a user visits my webpage (apache2)?

Comment: Yes. Possible read apache logs and if new entry trigger action.

Comment: It is also possible to trigger that bash script from php or what you are using. But this is not script writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your apache to run cgi scripts. You can use *any* executable file as cgi (C, Perl, shell - whatsoever).

Make sure you add proper 'execute' permissions so apache can run the file, then include on your page something like

```
<img src="/cgi-bin/myfile.sh">
```

and you're done!

If you do not have access to apache configuration:

```
<?php
....
system('/path/to/script.sh');
```

then include that php as `<img src...` too.